# Pre and Post Multiplication World Space Transform Matrix ambiguity

Tags: matrix, graphics, matrix-multiplication, rotational-matrices

I'm currently studying about world space transformation matrices and encountered some confusion regarding their application in different matrix orders (row major vs column major).

**Context**

- In row major order, a point is represented as  `[x,y,z]`
- In column major order, the same point is represented as `[[x], [y], [z]]`

**World Space Transformation**

- For column major order, we use post-multiplication: `P1 = WST * p1 = S * Rx * Ry * Rz * T * p1`
- For row major order, it's we use pre-multiplication: `P2 = p2 * WST = p2 * T * Rz * Ry * Rx * S`

However, I feel, for row major it should instead be: `P2 = p2 * WST' = p2 * T' * Rz' * Ry' * Rx' * S` where ' denotes transpose of the matrix.

**My Reasoning**

Both P1 and P2 represent the same transformed point, just in different orders (column major vs row major).

So, `P2 = P1' = (S * Rx * Ry * Rz * T *  p1)'`

Since, `(AB)' = B'A'`

We can say that, `P1 = p1' * T * Rz * Ry * Rx * S =  p2 * T * Rz * Ry * Rx * S` (as p1' = p2)